# How do i get rid of attribute error for my class in Python?

Tags: python

This error shows up when I run my code. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'vertices'`. I think I might have passed the parameter incorrectly for vertices. I'm trying to store the points in a list but do I not need to unpack with `*`?

Here is the beginning of my class:

```
class SimplePoly:
    def __init__(self, *vertices):
        self.vertices = list(vertices) ##attribute error
        ##tring to use a list of point instead of a list with one tuple 
        self.count = 0
        self.length = len(self.vertices)

    def translate(self, s, t):
        for i in self.vertices:
            i.translate(s,t)

    def rotate(self, degree):
        degree = math.radians(degree)
        for i in self.vertices:
            i.rotate(degree)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """return next vertex from polygon, raises exception if no more"""
        if self.count > self.length - 1:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            answer = self.vertices[self.count]
            self.count += 1
        return answer

    def __len__(self):
        """returns number of vertices in the polygon"""
        count = 0
        for i in self.vertices:
            count += 1
        return count

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """overloads the index operator"""
        if index < 0 or index > len(self.vertices):
            raise IndexError
        return self.vertices[index - 1]

    def __str__(self):
        points = []
        for i in self.vertices:
            points.append(str(i))
        return ','.join(points)
```

The error obtained is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/halled/Downloads/testpolys-3.py", line 111, in <module>
    octagon = RegularPoly(8)
  File "/Users/halled/Documents/polys.py", line 186, in __init__
    ConvPoly.__init__(vertices)
  File "/Users/halled/Documents/polys.py", line 178, in __init__
    SimplePoly.__init__(self, *vertices)
  File "/Users/halled/Documents/polys.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.vertices = list(vertices)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'vertices'
```

Comment: Can you please post how you are creating the object of your class ?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: I have a previous class called Point which sets up my x,y. But are you asking to see the rest of the SimplePoly class?

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the error post, I apologize, one sec.

Comment: The rest of my code is too long but that is supposed to be another class, ConvPoly, inheriting from SimplyPoly so im invoking the init of Simply Poly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code. It looks like `self` is an int at the second-last call, but that's all I can say without seeing the code that's actually causing the problem. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the traceback, Line 186 ("/Users/halled/Documents/polys.py") seems to be the problem.

```
ConvPoly.__init__(vertices)
```

You probably want this instead of the above line -

```
ConvPoly.__init__(self, vertices)
```

From traceback, `vertices` is set to 8.

`ConvPoly.__init__(vertices)` is called with vertices=8.

This in turn calls `SimplePoly.__init__(self, *vertices)`

Here, `self` gets `vertices` which is `int`.

As a result, exception is raised when `self.vertices = list(vertices)` is executed since `self` is pointing to 8 (`int`).